# kernel prompt <-> symbol

Tags: linux, kernel, prompt

When I configure the kernel then I get often prompt names in the manual I'm using. E.g it says: "activate Linux guest support". So when I type "/" I can search for strings, but it only searches the Symbol names like "HYPERVISOR_GUEST".

Is there a way to search for prompt names? Or can I somewhere see that "Linux guest support" belongs to "HYPERVISOR_GUEST" ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with `menuconfig` (nor with `nconfig`). You have to use something like:

```
find -name Kconfig | xargs grep "<YOUR SEARCH>"
```

However, I think patch for this feature would be welcome

Comment: do you know any c? im trying to patch it by myself.. but im not very skilled :(